'uv' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Windows when trying to create a virtual environment
I'm trying to create a virtual environment in Windows using the uv command, but I keep encountering the following error:
'uv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
1] Installation:
I installed uv using pip install uv within my Python environment.
I verified the installation by running pip list, and uv appears in the list of installed packages.
2] Path Configuration:
I checked my PATH environment variable and confirmed that the Python Scripts directory (where uv.exe should reside) is included.
I tried using the full path to the uv executable, but the error persists.
3] Environment Setup:
I ensured that my virtual environment was properly created and activated using:
python -m venv myenv
myenv\Scripts\activate
4] Other Commands:
Other Python-related commands like pip, python, etc., work fine without issues.
I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling uv but still face the same problem.
Why is the uv command not being recognized despite being installed and listed by pip? How can I resolve this issue and successfully create a virtual environment using uv?

Context for the duplicate: Some packages install an executable script on the system. As long as the directory for this script is present in the PATH you can execute them from anywhere. In the duplicate they have the same issue you have just for a different script from a different package.

first of all - are you 100% sure venv is activated? because python -m venv myenv AND myenv\Scripts\activate should be separate commands. Then if you are sure - check if uv is installed in virtual environment. because step-by-step installation you mentioned means that first you install uv to main package, then you launch venv, then you try use uv (inside venv)

no i was trying to activate the venv using uv using the command
"uv venv"
its giving an error that 'uv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
